# write a single entry to a text file

Tags: python, image, object, object-detection

My question is that I have the following text file as shown. I want to extract the integer parts in this file but single entry at a time so each single entry will be saved to a new txt file that has this name (0000.txt, 0001.txt, according to what is present in the file.and all of those text files will be saved under video0001 and so on with the same procedure until the text file is finished.

```
video_0001/00000.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 
video_0001/00001.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 
video_0002/00000.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 
video_0002/00000.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 
video_0003/00001.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0
```

Here's my code:

```
  with open('copy.txt', 'r') as rf:
    L = rf.readline()
    folder_name, file_name = L.split('/')
    filename, integers = file_name.split("\d")
    print(integers)
    #with open('0000.txt', 'w') as wf:
        #wf.write()
```

Any help would be appreciated

```
The expected results should be 
Video0001 (this is present in the text file and I have a directory named video0001 so I want to save those text file in it)
     Have a 0000.txt (This file contains 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 ) [should be saved with the same name as in the second column. 

Video0001
      0000.txt [  465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 ]          
      0001.txt [  465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 ] 
Video002 
     0000.txt [465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0] 
     0002.txt [465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0]
```

These folders should match my own folders saved with same name locally and save .txt file according to the above description

Comment: what is the problem? We can't run this code, and we can't read in your mind - you have to describe all details in question. If you get wrong result then show it and describe what is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand your code. You get all `dirname` but you never use it. You import `re` but you never use it. Maybe first clean your code.

Comment: I have the same directory name (video0001) folders saved I was trying to match the first entry with those folder so I can save my new text file in them

Comment: maybe show expected result for your example file

Comment: maybe you should split line on first space to get `path` and `rest` as text - and later get number from path and write `rest` in file - `path, rest = L.split(" ", 1)` - `number = path.split("/")[1].split(".")[0]`

Comment: @furas can u please check my edit,

Comment: if you want to save in folders then maybe you should get full `video_0001/00000.png` and only replace `.png` with `.txt` - to get path for new file.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more with an example

Comment: `new_path = "video_0001/00000.png".replace(".png", ".txt")` and you get `new_path` with `video_0001/00000.txt` which you use in `open(new_path, 'w')`

Comment: @furas any thoughts on how to go over each single entry and save them

Comment: @furas the video names and  the file names are changing per each entry is there a generic way I can use to be applied for all entries in the text file as shown above

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. If names can be different then you should show it in question (not in comments). You have to show all details in question because we can't read in your mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save in the same folders then you could get full path `video_0001/00000.png` and replace `.png` with `.txt` and use this path `video_0001/00000.txt` in `open()`

If you run code in different folder then you may need to use string with `'/absolute/path/to/video_0001/00000.txt'`

If you have folders without `_` then you can add `.replace('_', '')`.

If you have folders with upper `V` instead of lower `v` then you can add `.replace('v', 'V')`

---

Something like this:

I use `io` only to simulate file in memory - so every one can copy and run it - but you should use `open()` to read from real file.

```
text = '''video_0001/00000.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 
video_0001/00001.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 
video_0002/00000.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 
video_0002/00000.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 
video_0003/00001.png 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0'''

import io

#with open('copy.txt', 'r') as rf:
with io.StringIO(text) as rf:

    for line in rf:

        old_path, data = line.split(" ", 1)

        data = data.strip()

        new_path = old_path.replace('.png', '.txt')
        new_path = new_path.replace('_', '')
        new_path = new_path.replace('v', 'V')
        #new_path = '/absolute/path/to/' + new_path

        print('old_path:', old_path)
        print('new_path:', new_path)
        print('data:', data)
        print('---')
    
        with open(new_path, 'w') as wf:
            wf.write(data)
```

it displays:

```
old_path: video_0001/00000.png
new_path: Video0001/00000.txt
data: 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0
---
old_path: video_0001/00001.png
new_path: Video0001/00001.txt
data: 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0
---
old_path: video_0002/00000.png
new_path: Video0002/00000.txt
data: 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0
---
old_path: video_0002/00000.png
new_path: Video0002/00000.txt
data: 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0
---
old_path: video_0003/00001.png
new_path: Video0003/00001.txt
data: 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0
```

---

Comment: thank u so much, is there a way of having the data that has two  entries 465,730,533,848,0 1398,654,1486,892,0 have the second entry at the second line of the same text. should i use strip as well

Comment: data should be for the second entry on the second line instead of the same line. @furas data: 465,730,533,848,0 \newline 1398,654,1486,892,0    in the same text file instead of the one line display

Comment: simply `data = data.replace(" ", "\n")`

Comment: thank you. is there a way of having the 0 start at the beginning of the text file of each line instead of the end so the file has the following
0, 465,730,533,848 \newline 0, 1398,654,1486,892

Comment: is there a way of having the 0 start at the beginning of the text file of ou.each line instead of the end so the file has the following
0, 465,730,533,848 \newline 0, 1398,654,1486,892, it tried to strip it and append it to the beginning of the text file but it does not seem to work. is there any other efficient way of doing it @furas

Comment: first remove `replace(",0", "")` and next add at the beginnig `"0," + data`  and add after new line `.replace(" ", "\n0,")`

Comment: it works perfectly right but after the last line it prints an extra zero. @furas Here's an example:  
0 465,730,533,848
0 1398,654,1486,892
0

Comment: maybe you have space at the end of line and this make problem. Use .replace(" ", "\n0,", 1) to replace only first space